# How to do this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there any workaround to do this integral?

```
Integrate[(x^2+2 x+1+(3 x+1) Sqrt[x+Log[x]])/(x Sqrt[x+Log[x]] (x+Sqrt[x+Log[x]])),x]
```

Comment: This is likely to be more of a math than Mathematica question. That said, maybe somebody has some ideas, e.g. a good substitution, that can be implemented in Mathematica. Assuming there is a reasonable antiderivative for this.

Comment: What do you want to do with the integral?  A numerical approach might be useful....

Comment: Someone claims the result is https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/3/4/8340d7ad13f5630d7d492b8fe243f859.png. I'm trying to obtain this result with Mma.

Comment: @MichaelE2, shouldn't that be obvious?  I want what Integrate should normally do.

Comment: "I want what Integrate should normally do" -- That doesn't seem to be an answer to my question.  Well, never mind, then, if that's all you want.  Sorry  for the bother.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* needs some hints:

```
integrand = (1 + 2 x + x^2 + (1 + 3 x) Sqrt[x + Log[x]]) /
  (x Sqrt[x + Log[x]] (x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]));

usub = First@Solve[
   {Dt[y] == (integrand + 2) Dt[x],     (* Hint 1: Add 2 *)
     u == x + v,                        (* Hint 2: u == x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]] *)
     Dt[u == x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]]} /.  (* Hint 3: Treat Sqrt[x + Log[x]] as atomic v *)
      {Sqrt[x + Log[x]] -> v, 1/Sqrt[x + Log[x]] -> 1/v},
   {Dt[y]}, {Dt[x], x}
   ]
(*  {Dt[y] -> (2 (Dt[u] + u Dt[u]))/u}  *)

(Integrate[Dt[y] /. usub /. Dt[u] -> 1, u] /. u -> x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]) -
 Integrate[2, x]
(*  -2 x + 2 (x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]) + 2 Log[x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]]  *)
```

Check:

```
D[%, x] - integrand // Simplify
(*  0  *)
```

Well, it's a difficult substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Because you know the potential answer, would it not be simple to differentiate:

```
integrand = (x^2 + 2 x + 1 + (3 x + 1) Sqrt[x + Log[x]])/
  (x Sqrt[x + Log[x]] (x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]));
integral = 2 (Sqrt[x + Log[x]] + Log[x + Sqrt[x + Log[x]]]);
FullSimplify[integrand - D[integral, x]]
(* 0 *)
```

(And I do realize that claiming "FullSimplify" did it isn't a proof.)