# Can I make Wolfram Alpha use a specific substitution when integrating?

Tags: syntax, wolfram-alpha-queries, integral-equations

Can I define the '$u = \dots$' for an integral?

For example when I integrate $\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{6 - x^2}}$ with respect to $x$, the program automatically sets $u = x^2$, how can I change this so it uses $u = (6 - x^2)$ or some other value?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146458/problem-with-evaluation-of-the-integral/146491#146491 There's also [`DChange`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80241/analogue-for-maples-dchange-change-of-variables-in-differential-expressions), but I think you need to write the integral as a differential equation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question seems about how to formulate W|A input and not about how to use *Mathematica* to communicate with W|A.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are trying to do

```
expr = x^3/Sqrt[6 - x^2];

int = Integrate[expr, x]

(* -(1/3) Sqrt[6 - x^2] (12 + x^2) *)
```

Checking that `int` is an anti-derivative of `expr`

```
expr == D[int, x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

The change of variables `u == (6 - x^2)` does not change the result

```
Integrate[
   (x^3/Sqrt[6 - x^2] /. x -> Sqrt[6 - u])* D[Sqrt[6 - u], u],
   u] /. u -> 6 - x^2 // Simplify

(* -(1/3) Sqrt[6 - x^2] (12 + x^2) *)
```

You can add any arbitrary constant to `int` and still have a valid anti-derivative

Comment: Clearly, the OP does not use Mathematica. What the OP is trying to ask is how to perform the change of variables using W|A. I'm having this issue too