# Is it possible to get this 'nicer' solution for an integral from Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

On a recent CAS-enabled exam question a few weeks ago I was required to evaluate the following integral:

$$
\int_0^5\left(\sqrt[3]{125-x^3}\right)^2\,dx
$$

In Mathematica, using the `Integrate` function returns this answer:

```
Integrate[(125-x^3)^(2/3),{x,0,5}]
```

$$
75\cdot 3^{2/3} F_1\left(\frac{5}{3};-\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3};\frac{8}{3};-\frac{1}{-1+(-1)^{2/3}},\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{-1}}\right)
$$
Where $F_1$ represents the [AppellF1 function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AppellF1.html).

However, on a TI-Nspire CX CAS, the same integral evaluates to:
$$\frac{500\pi}{9\sqrt3}$$

That's a much nicer looking answer!

Both of these have the same numerical value of about $100.767$, which tells me that both answers appear to be equivalent - but is it possible to get the CX's more concise answer in Mathematica? I've tried wrapping each of these functions around Mathematica's answer, but none of them have worked:

- `RootReduce`
- `FullSimplify`
- `FunctionExpand`
- `ToRadicals`
- `ComplexExpand`
- adding `Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals` to the `Integrate` function

All of these seem to keep the F1 function in place, sometimes changing the arguments slightly, but still keeping the F1 function there, more or less the same. If it is possible, how could I get the simpler answer in Mathematica? I'm on 11.3.0 for macOS (64-bit), if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: _v9.0.1_ gives the simple answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8oCg.png Which version are you in? How did you code it?

Comment: I get the same result as OP (the Appel function) on 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: I'm on 11.3.0 for macOS.

Comment: We are nearing the point when Mathematica will give correct but unusable answers only to be left alone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Integrate`InverseIntegrate[(125 - x^3)^(2/3), {x, 0, 5}]

(*(500 π)/(9 Sqrt[3])*)
```

`` Integrate`InverseIntegrate `` this is an [undocumented function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/incorrect-results-for-elementary-integrals-when-using-integrate/6695#6695).

---

Another [method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146458/problem-with-evaluation-of-the-integral/146491#146491) borrowed code from user: [Michael-E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2), is using substitution:`125 - x^3 == t^3`

```
ClearAll[trysub];
SetAttributes[trysub, HoldFirst];
trysub[Integrate[int_, x_], sub_Equal, u_] := Module[{sol, newint}, sol = Solve[sub, x];
newint = int*Dt[x] /. Last[sol] /. Dt[u] -> 1 // Simplify;
Integrate[newint, u] /. Last@Solve[sub, u] // Simplify];

Assuming[t > 0 && x ∈ Reals, int = trysub[Integrate[(125 - x^3)^(2/3), x], 125 - x^3 == t^3, t]]

(* 1/3 (125 - x^3)^(2/3) ((x^3)^(1/3) - 5 Hypergeometric2F1[2/3, 2/3, 5/3, 1 - x^3/125]) *)

(Limit[int, x -> 5]) - (Limit[int, x -> 0]) // FullSimplify(* Is function continuous !!! *)

(*(500 π)/(9 Sqrt[3])*)
```

Answer (score 17):

You can always compare to [Rubi's solution](https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi) which is often able to produce better antiderivatives.

Installation in Mathematica 11.3:

```
Needs["PacletManager`"];
PacletInstall[
  "https://github.com/RuleBasedIntegration/Rubi/releases/download/4.15.2.1/Rubi-4.15.2.1.paclet"
];
```

Then you can solve the integral

```
<< Rubi`
int = Int[((125 - x^3)^(1/3))^2, x]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Taking the limits at both ends

```
(Limit[int, x -> 5, Direction -> "FromBelow"]) - 
(Limit[int, x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"])
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[%]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Edit

For completeness and since KraZug mentioned it in the comment: Rubi can calculate the limits and the difference automatically, but be aware that it is not the same what `Integrate[expr, {x, a, b}]` does. `Integrate` is more powerful in this regard and takes care of discontinuities between the boundaries.

```
Int[((125 - x^3)^(1/3))^2, {x, 0, 5}] // Simplify
(* (500 \[Pi])/(9 Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Comment: Why not just `int = Int[((125 - x^3)^(1/3))^2, {x,0,5}]//Simplify`?

Comment: Because I didn't want to imply that this is equivalent to `Integrate`'s form with boundaries. It basically does the same (without the directions if I remember correctly) and if someone is interested, he will find the `Int[expr,{x,a,b}]` usage on the README I've written and which is directly behind the link :)
But yes, I could have simply used the shorter form..

Comment: The explanation as to why it is not the same is useful though, because it is not obvious to me.

Comment: You can't simply apply the Fundemental Theorem of Calculus if the anti-derivative is not continuous between the limits of integration. Integrate in Mathematica works very hard to get this right, and the above answer using Rubi does nothing to check for discontinuities between 0 and 5. for more on this see,  https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/01/19/mathematica-and-the-fundamental-theorem-of-calculus/

Answer (score 16):

I get the same result as in the OP (10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)). A possibility to get the correct answer is to Taylor-expand, integrate term-wise, and re-sum.

```
SeriesCoefficient[(125 - x^3)^(2/3), {x, 0, n}]
(* (5^(2 - n) (1/3 (-5 + n))!)/((-(5/3))! (n/3)!) if Mod[n,3]==0, zero otherwise *)

Integrate[% x^n, {x, 0, 5}]
(* (125 Gamma[1/3 (-2 + n)])/((1 + n) (n/3)! Gamma[-(2/3)]) if Mod[n,3]==0, zero otherwise *)

Sum[% /. n -> 3 n, {n, 0, Infinity}]
(* (500 Pi)/(9 Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Of course, this is somewhat hacky, but at least it proves that the "simple" result is correct.

--

Alternative: if you slightly generalise the integral, it returns the compact result:

```
Integrate[(a^3 - x^3)^(2/3), {x, 0, a}]
(* (4 a^3 Pi)/(9 Sqrt[3]) *)
% /. a-> 5
(* (500 Pi)/(9 Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Weird, huh?

Comment: That's actually quite funny: if I use `Integrate[(a^3 - x^3)^(2/3), {x, 0, a}]`, I get a conditional expression with the condition of `Re[a] > 0 && Im[a] == 0`. But if I instead use `Integrate[(a^3 - x^3)^(2/3), {x, 0, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]` hoping that the assumption will remove `ConditionalExpression`, I get a long result in terms of `AppellF1` and `Hypergeometric2F1` on Mathematica 11.2, although not on 10.1.

Comment: @Ruslan I was using `$Assumptions = a > 1`, but I'm using MMA 10.4. Interesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
{ymin, ymax} = Through[{MinValue, MaxValue}[{(125 - x^3)^(2/3), 0 <= x <= 5}, x]]
expr = x /. First@Normal@Solve[y == (125 - x^3)^(2/3), x, Reals]
Integrate[expr, {y, ymin, ymax}]
```

> {0, 25}
>
> Root[-125 + Sqrt[y^3] + #1^3 &, 1]
>
> (500 Pi)/(9 Sqrt[3])